# I'm Unable to spider the web page after form-based authentication using Zap-Cli

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I'm using Zap-Cli, a command line tool for Owasp ZAP. I'm successful in creating a context for the web page but unable to spider the web page after authentication. It's being done with the GUI tool, but me and my team are working on automating the process from command line. We are stuck at this point. Providing some important links for your convenience.

https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli
https://gist.github.com/kvkvenugopal/1428626e0201a746e390e03880356376

Waiting for help/suggestions. We are trying for 2 weeks now. Everything upto this point is working from the command line. We are able to open the URL, and create a context for authentication. After this point, if we are running spider from the GUI then it is working, but not from the command line.

If required, kindly ask for further details. My team thinks there's some issue with the current ZAP API which is not allowing for spider after authentication from command line.

Any expert suggestion/advice will be helpful.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

The ZAP API does support authentication, but you'll need to set it up as per https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth
I'm afraid I dont know if the Zap-Cli supports this - have you raised an issue on that tool?

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Yes Simon I've raised the issue and Grunny has replied for the same. It's still not possible with Zap-Cli, but my team is working on it and if we succeed then we'll let Grunny know and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know:)